# Resize browser and add files online in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have an easy script that adds any files depending on the screen extension.
But, this does not work for the browser when the screen changes.
How to upload files in a script changing the size of the browser live?

I know about "resize" in jquery, but it's not working.

```
{
if (screen.width > 601) document.write ('<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/one.js"></sc' + 'ript>');
else if (screen.width <= 600) document.write ('<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/two.js"></sc' + 'ript>'); 
if (screen.width < 990) document.write ('<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/three.js"></sc' + 'ript>');    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your this code before `</body>` tag like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/one.js" id="script_var"></script>

<script>
 $(window).on('resize', function () {
    var sw = $(window).width();
  if (sw < 900) {
      $('#script_var').attr("src", "/js/two.js");
    } else if (sw > 900) {
      $('#script_var').attr("src", "/js/three.js");
    }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onresize function in body element.

```
<body onresize="myFunction()">


function myFunction() {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    //write your code here
}
```